# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes when I run Firefox

Tags: firefox, freeze

I am facing Ubuntu 20.04 long freeze issue when I am trying to use Firefox.
Firefox opens fine the first time, but it could freeze if I try to open a new window or may be try to check on about firefox window.

**The steps I have taken are:**

Update Ubuntu to the latest software; problem still exists

Uninstall Ubuntu Firefox install and install direct from Mozilla; problem still exists.

**When running Firefox from command line, I see the following message:**

```
hko@e64ubuntu:~/Downloads/firefox/firefox-99.0.1/firefox$ ./firefox &
[1] 2153 
hko@e64ubuntu:~/Downloads/firefox/firefox-99.0.1/firefox$
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment. 
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment. 
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
 **[GFX1-]: wr_renderer_render: OutOfMemory
   [GFX1-]: Fallback WR to SW-WR**
```

I have already tried Ubuntu original (deb or snap) install and had issues. I don't see the issue if I use nomodeset during the boot. However the graphics are dull and choppy with nomodeset.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try installing the .deb version instead of the snap.... It's available in the Ubuntu software center (as the snap version) rather than from mozilla.

Comment: 'purge', 'clean', 'autoremove' and 'install' doesn't help! It is still stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Settings > Performance

- Use recommended performance settings
- Use Hardware acceleration

Turn these off.